# This error "DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions" does not stop

Tags: discord.js

I have a problem, and that is that every moment I get this error: `DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions` and I don't know where it comes from or why

Comment: Your bot probably doesn't have permissions to do the actions you are asking it to do

Comment: We need more information to help you. When does this error occur? What is your client attempting to do?

Comment: i don't have more information :c

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure if anyone will still run into this issue but if you do. It could be a problem with your BOT being a lower level than the user or whatever your trying to do. For example most people have the Owner role on the top right? right. Well if you're trying to do something to a user above your bot like if the role BOT is under MEMBER and you try Banning MEMBER with BOT it won't work. Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

In 2021 this error can be fixed, if you are trying to let's say for example to create a ban all command for your discord bot, **YOU HAVE TO DO THIS BEFORE GIVING UP ON IT**. First go to https://discord.com/developers/applications and click on your bot's account then go to the option bot(the location were you get the bot token) then turn on those options:

[image]

EASY DIRECTIONS: *Discord Developer Portal>(Click on your bot's account)>Bot(the place were you are getting the token from)>Privileged Gateway Intents>PRESENCE INTENT(TURN IT ON IF IT'S OFF)>SERVER MEMBERS INTENT(IT'S LOCATED IN THE SAME PAGE, TURN IT ON IF IT'S OFF)* Those are the main thing that you have to do and then you can start to make your command!

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answers given, I also needed to go to Server Settings > Roles. There you have a draggable list of roles available on your server. Drag your bots auto-assigned role (the bots name) to the top of the list. This will give it permission to assign subordinate roles.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and it was because that I didn't give my bot the role to write in the channel. So make sure that your bot has the persmission to your channel.

Comment: Yes. It's important to prioritize the bot role over the subordinate roles by dragging it to the first position.