# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning discord js music bot

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a discord js music bot but when I change the song in it this error comes and after getting this error few times I get 403 error code and I have to restart the bot again

```
(node:248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/jammashama-1/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/jammashama-1/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async GuildMember.edit (/home/runner/jammashama-1/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildMember.js:312:5)
(node:248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:248) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Error: write EPIPE
ID: ubgFZnja_HE
Name: TheFatRat - Fly Away (Lyrics) feat. Anjulie
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16) {
  errno: 'EPIPE',
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
(node:248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/jammashama-1/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/jammashama-1/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async GuildMember.edit (/home/runner/jammashama-1/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildMember.js:312:5)
(node:248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related errors on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning+DiscordAPIError:+Missing+Permissions+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<***

Comment: I think your question was answered here [This error "DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions" does not stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58157006/this-error-discordapierror-missing-permissions-does-not-stop)

Answer (score -1):

> DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

The problem is that your bot does not have the required permissions.