# When I try to kick someone on Discord using bot I get an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, discord.js, bots

when I try to kick someone using a bot I made it keeps on giving a error. I followed CodeLyons tutorial on ban and kicking. which is his 2020 discord bot playlist. This is the error that keeps coming:

(node:5108) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
/home/ayan/Desktop/DiscordBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350
throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
at RequestHandler.execute (/home/ayan/Desktop/DiscordBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (/home/ayan/Desktop/DiscordBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
at async GuildMemberManager.kick (/home/ayan/Desktop/DiscordBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberManager.js:363:5) {
method: 'delete',
path: '/guilds/927169002294345758/members/895937895456735233',
code: 50013,
httpStatus: 403,
requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}

my code:

main.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const prefix = '!';

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [ Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES ]
});

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Chilly is online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    if (command === 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'kick') {
        client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'ban') {
        client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login('***********************************');
```

kick.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(message, args) {
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        //if (message.member.roles.cache.has('927171204371079208')) {
            if (member) {
                const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
                memberTarget.kick();
                message.channel.send("User has been kicked");
            } else {
                message.channel.send("You couldn't kick that member");
            }
        //} else {
            //message.channel.send("Sorry you don't have the right permissions to send this message");
        //}
    }
}
```

extra info:
library: discord.js
nodejs version: 16.13

Comment: Did you know that you posted the credentials on this question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This error "DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions" does not stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58157006/this-error-discordapierror-missing-permissions-does-not-stop)

Comment: Zsolt I followed that question and did what it says, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine.

The error means that the bot does not have the `KICK_MEMBERS` permission you can fix this by giving the bot admin or the `KICK_MEMBERS` permission. It could also mean that the bot can't kick the member because they are the owner and/or higher then the bots role

Comment: Turtlepaw thanks for the answer. "It could also mean that the bot can't kick the member because they are the owner and/or higher then the bots role", I noticed I had my alt account with staff permissions (higher than bot) so when I removed staff I was able to my alt account!